# Foreign Key in DAO with Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, foreign-keys, dao

I know its a pretty dumb question but I can't find it anywhere. If I have two tables in a database like something like:

```
CREATE TABLE salary {
    ID int,
    salary float,
    primary key (ID),
}
CREATE TABLE employee { 
    ID int,
    salary_ID int,
    primary key (ID),
    foreign key(salary_ID) references salary (ID)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
}
```

when I need to put it in java to make the DAO. How exactly will be the employer class? something like:

```
    public class employee {
            private int ID, salary_ID;

            public employer (int ID, int salary_ID){
                    this.ID=ID;
                    this.salary_ID=salary_ID;
            }
            public String getID(){
                            return ID;
            }
            public void setID(int num){
                    num= ID;        
            }
            public String getSalaryID(){
                    return salary_ID;
            }
            public void setSalaryID(int num){
                    num= salary_ID;     
            }
    }
```

or

```
    public class employee {
            private int ID;

            public employer (int ID){
                    this.ID=ID;
            }
            public String getID(){
                    return ID;
            }
            public void setID(int num){
                    num= ID;        
            }
    }
```

what I'm trying to ask is... How do I must put an foreign key? How java knows there is a relationship between the two tables? Preferably in the most simply way and without using any framework to help.

Comment: Have you considered just using JPA instead of hand-rolling an ORM?

Comment: actually I just used the only way that the teacher showed us but she showed no example with two tables with a relationship. I`m even learning those abreviations now while I search for the answer. All that she said was that this was a Persistence layer using Java.

Comment: Java doesn't (and cannot) know about the relationships between tables. It is up to the programmer to feed valid data into the database. If there is a FK relationship between the tables, then the best way to eliminate FK violations is to only allow inserting valid keys from the _user interface_; e.g. by using a dropdown of pre-fetched values matching the FK, instead of using free-text fields.

Answer (score 1):

You could embed a salary object within an employee object

```
public class Employee {
    private int ID;
    private Salary salary;
    ...
    ....
}
```